# Powershell compare returned results

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I currently have a Power Shell Script that uses WMI to query the computer for the Service Tag/Serial Number & then uses a SOAP request to query Dell's Website to get the Warranty Information. The Problem is that for some computers I receive multiple results in the Query instead of a single Warranty Date. What I need to do is be able to compare the returned values to get the correct Warranty Information. I think that I need to parse the returned results into an array and then do a comparison but I am not sure. Any help is appreciated.

```
$c = 'localhost'
$service = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri https://xserv.dell.com/services/assetservice.asmx?WSDL
$system = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $c win32_bios -ErrorActionSilentlyContinue
$serial =  $system.serialnumber
$guid = [guid]::NewGuid()
$info = $service.GetAssetInformation($guid,'check_warranty.ps1',$serial)
$info | Select-Object -ExpandProperty entitlements | Where-Object {$_.ServiceLevelCode -eq "SV" -or $_.ServiceLevelCode -eq "TS"}
```

Here is the returned result for a Single Computer:

```
ServiceLevelCode: TS
ServiceLevelDescription : ProSupport
Provider                : DELL
StartDate               : 8/8/2014 12:00:00 AM
EndDate                 : 8/7/2016 12:00:00 AM
DaysLeft                : 306
EntitlementType         : Active

ServiceLevelCode        : TS
ServiceLevelDescription : ProSupport
Provider                : DELL
StartDate               : 8/7/2013 12:00:00 AM
EndDate                 : 8/7/2014 12:00:00 AM
DaysLeft                : 0
EntitlementType         : Expired
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should only get valid warranties? I have dell machines as well but I do not know if there would be more that one of those that is valid. If there was you should still expect more that one result. So you could try this:

```
$info | Select-Object -ExpandProperty entitlements | 
    Where-Object {$_.ServiceLevelCode -in "SV","TS" -and $_.EntitlementType -eq "Active"} | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty EndDate
```

You could just do a sort as well and pick the newest. Still hard to say. This would be fine if there was only one valid entitlement.

```
$info | Select-Object -ExpandProperty entitlements | 
    Where-Object {$_.ServiceLevelCode -eq "SV" -or $_.ServiceLevelCode -eq "TS"} | 
    Sort-Object -Property @{Expression=[datetime]$_.EndDate} |
    Select -First 1
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, Unfortunately I am unaware of how to get Valid Warranties. I think the key for me is to find a way to compare the end date of the returned results and pick the one that is the newest date ie 8/7/2016 12:00:00 AM is newer than 8/7/2014 12:00:00 AM

Comment: @Raproductions That is exactly what his `Sort` method does. It sorts the results based on the `EndDate` property and selects the first one.

Comment: @Raproductions `$_.EntitlementType -eq "Active"` gets valid and _active_  warranties. Its an attribute of what you show in your question. Barring the the second code get the entry with the latest end date. So in theory that date is the last date you will have _some form_ of warranty. My issue is there are several flavours of dell warranty.

Comment: @Matt I would agree with you however you still want to receive the results of a warranty that is expired.

Comment: @Raproductions I am confused about what you want since it seemed like you only wanted one of the results. What are you trying to do since the results are already an array?

Comment: @Matt Yes I only wanted one of the results which was the last Warranty Date. IE when does the Warranty finally expire or is it currently expired for the Machine. I didn't know the results where returned in an array already.

Comment: @Raproductions So if that is what you wanted the examples I have above essentially do that.

Comment: @Matt Unfortunately the examples above did not return the results. Your first example just showed Active Warranties if a warranty is expired it would not be shown.  The second example when sorted just gave the expired warranty not the active warranty on 2 of the 3 test machines.

Comment: @Raproductions The second one might just need and `-Descending` for the `Sort-Object`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I used to get the Dell Warranty from 95% of the Dell Computers I currently manage. I took this and created a Function for each piece and then use the function to pull the Data into the SQL Table that we use for Inventory.

```
$serviceTag = [string]$SerialNumber = (Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\cimv2" -Class Win32_SystemEnclosure).SerialNumber
$WebProxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri 'http://xserv.dell.com/services/AssetService.asmx?WSDL' -UseDefaultCredential
$WebProxy.Url = 'http://xserv.dell.com/services/AssetService.asmx'
$WarrantyInformation = $WebProxy.GetAssetInformation(([guid]::NewGuid()).Guid, "Dell Warranty", $serviceTag)
$WarrantyInformation | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Entitlements | Where-Object {$_.ServiceLevelCode -eq "SV" -or $_.ServiceLevelCode -eq "TS"} | ForEach-Object {
$StartDate=[datetime]$_.StartDate 
$EndDate=[datetime]$_.EndDate
[string]$Provider=$_.Provider
[string]$DaysLeft=$_.DaysLeft
[string]$Status=$_.EntitleMentType
$warrantydays = New-TimeSpan -start $StartDate -end $EndDate 
if ($warrantydays.Days -gt 366){
 write-host ("Provider: "+ $Provider)
 write-host ("Status: " + $Status)
 write-host ("Days Left: " + $DaysLeft)
 write-host ("Start Date: " + $StartDate)
 write-host ("End Date: " + $EndDate)
 }
}
```